# Export one voice as mid or wav with beat intro in MuseScore

Tags: musescore

How do I separate a project into a number of sound files, each with only one voice (SATB) and with a three beats intro in the beginning? It would also be nice to have some extra beats where that specific voice is silent. An underlying question is how do I specify which notes that belongs to a certain voice. Do I have to give them a color?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion (at least that’s how I did it):

- Go to Edit -> Instruments
- Add a drum staff (under percussion - unpitched)
- Insert one or two more bars before where you start your piece. Type in the beats as you desire in your intro on the drum staff. (I usually have closed hi-hats playing 4 crotchet beats)
- If you want, go to Style -> General, and hide empty staves.
- Go to File -> Parts -> New
- Choose a name for the part you want to create, e.g. Soprano. Type that under **Part Title**.
- Tick both the Soprano voice part and your percussion (drums) part in the boxes below, and click OK.

**NOTE:** I’m assuming your SATB score is in 4 different staves, if not you have to first explode them, under Edit -> Tools -> Explode

- Now, you should have your Soprano only score generated (with the percussion). You can export it and save as mp3).
- Do the same for your other parts. When you’re done exporting all 4 mp3, you can go back to your main score and remove the drum staff + the extra measure in front.

Have fun! :)